# generation text with controlled parameters on images using Python

Tags: python, string, controls

I need to write simple generator of text on images using Python. Strings must be generated with any font, size, incline of symbols, boldness. And what is more important, I need to know precize position (with bounding boxes) any of symbol in text. Text maybe any size fitted on image.
Thanks, Alexey.

Comment: So what did you try what is your question exactly ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I tried to use PIL module in Python and few other string generating methods on images, but I haven't found in any of them possibility to getting precise positions (or bounding box) of every symbols (character or digit). This is the main of what I need. Also I haven't found how to change incline of symbols.